# Substitute a PHP variable name according to its value

Tags: php, variables, substitution

I have the following variables set:

```
$type = 'cd';
$type_cd = 'Compact Disc';
```

`$type`'s value is stored in MySQL database and could be whatever.

But in some specific place of the code I need to `echo $type_cd;` instead of `echo $type;` in case `$type = 'cd';`.

I want to avoid constructions like `if($type = 'cd') {echo $type_cd;}`, using the minimum possible code.

Is it possible with PHP to create something like `$newvar = $ + prefix + oldvar_value`?

Comment: I understand all surrealistic of my example but have no idea how to describe my goal in other words.

Comment: It might make more sense to create an array: `$type = 'cd'; $types = ['cd' => 'Compact Disc', ...];` and then just do: `echo $types[$type];`. Then you only need one variable for all of them and can dynamically get the correct value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I see no big difference between an array and huge number of `if() {}`s. It is what I eagerly want to avoid.

Comment: It's a huge difference. You will still need to define `$type_cd = 'Compact Disc';` somewhere, which you just replace with `'cd' => 'Compact Disc'` in the array. Then when you echo it, you replace all `ìf`'s with one single line: `echo $types[$type];`. How is removing all `if`'s and contain all values in one single variable (which you can pass around if needed and debug easily while not cluttering the global namespace with a bunch of variables) not a big difference?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hmm... indeed )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array instead of multiple variables. You can define these in some class or in some config so you can reuse them where ever:

```
$availableTypes = [
    'cd'  => 'Compact Disc',
    'foo' => 'bar', 
    ...
];
```

Then when you get the type from the database, all you need to do is:

```
$type = 'cd'; // Fetched from your database

echo $availableTypes[$type];
```

Comment: In my case it returns `1` instead of `Compact Disc` and `Compact Disc` right over the parent tag. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @Pimpfru - It's kind of impossible to say what you've done wrong since I can't see your code. But here's a working demo: https://3v4l.org/SWbMr

Comment: While I can not see how it was possible the result appeared correct after I've resaved and reuploaded the page. Thank you! Your solution is really the closest to what I was trying to achieve. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
$a = 'ab';
$ab = 2
echo $$a; // 2
```

For your example:

```
$type = 'cd';
$type_cd = 'Compact Disc';

// a variable that holds the type
$temp_type = $is_cd ? 'type' : 'type_cd';

echo $$temp_type;
```

Comment: May I please ask you to edit your example with my data?

Comment: here you have it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$type = 'cd';
$$type = 'Compact Disc';
echo $cd;
```

It will echo "Compact Disc".
I do not see it as best practice...
You can find the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: I've read this article before asking ). In two words I needed to echo `$type` and substitute the value with `Compact Disc` instead of `cd`. I now see that using an array is really the best practice.

Comment: Yes. I would use an array as well.